# Populate control using model of another control - smartphone issue

Tags: sapui5

I tried to get the model of the control situated on another view and apply this model to the control on current view.
To do so, I've put the following code into onBeforeRendering() function of the controller:

```
var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().byId('<id of the control in another view>').getModel('<modelName here>');
sap.ui.getCore().byId('<id of the control in the current view>').setModel(oModel, "<modelName here>");
```

The problem is that this construction works well on PC and tablet (android) (the control - sap.m.select - is populated with items), but this does not work on smartphone (android) (sap.m.select control is empty).

How do I solve this?

Comment: Are both views being rendered on the phone? Models are only available if the views are rendered.

Comment: Yes, both are rendered. I use SplitApp control and the first view is rendered when the application starts. The second is rendered when I navigate to it.

Comment: Hi, why don't you use a global model that can be shared by both views? For example you could do `sap.ui.getCore().setModel(<your shared model data>, <model name>);` and then reference the model by using `sap.ui.getCore().getModel(<model name>);` on both views. Let me know if this will work for you. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mjd suggested in the comment, I've used global model:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(<shared model data>, "<modelName>");
```

and then just used the model by its name.

For example:

in page1.controller:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(data, "selection");
```

and then in page2.view (the same construction is used in page1.view):

```
var oSelection = new sap.m.Select({
    id:     'selectionID',
    items: {
        path: "selection>/rootElementName", 
        template: new sap.ui.core.Item({
            text: "{selection>elementName}"
        })
    },
});
```